# Google Drive upload fails on files larger than ~10MB using .NET client library

Tags: google-drive-api, google-api-dotnet-client

We've written a .Net console app that uploads files to a specific google Drive account. The code uses google's own .net client library. The heart of the code is this:-

```
FilesResource.InsertMediaUpload upload = service.Files.Insert(metadata, fStream, mimeType);
upload.Upload();
metadataReturned = upload.ResponseBody;
```

The app is working fine for all files smaller than a certain limit, which seems to be around 10MB. With larger files the upload fails with an exception, the message being "The request was aborted: The request was canceled."

We would appreciate any suggestions on how to upload larger files, or any explanation for the exception.

Comment: Please install Fiddler and capture the requests to see the complete error message. The upload request is a resumable one, so it should upload your file in chunk to prevent timeouts. You can also try setting the ChunkSize property in the request to see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks, we will investigate the chunksize property

Comment: We have decided to go back to using the Google Data API (Google Docs v1) rather than the Google-api-dotnet-client as the async upload works as expected.

Comment: Please note that the Documents List API was deprecated as of September 14, 2012

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a bug.
Can you please open an issue in the [issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/list) (this is the best way to report bugs, requests, etc.), and try to provide as much information as you can, like the Google's client library's version, the OS you ran the code, etc.

I'll try to get into it ASAP.

Thank you,
Eyal

Comment: A new issue were added to the issue tracker - https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/detail?id=296

Comment: As Claudio mentioned GData is deprecated, so you won't get any support or new features in it. 

I investigated your bug, and it looks like I need more details - can you provide fiddler data as well? 
I ran similar code to yours and it worked for a ~25MB file with different chunk sizes.

Comment: Hi Eyal
Many Thanks for raising this as an issue and for looking into it. We are happy to send you some code and system specs, but what is the easiest way of giving you more detail? Post directly here or send to an email address? We have never used Fiddler; how much work is involved in setting it up? Thanks Harry

Comment: Setting fiddler is very easy, you can download it from http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/ and you are ready to go. Please notice also that I'm currently working on improving ResumableUpload to support server errors, so in a couple of weeks you will be able to pull the latest version from our repository and your media upload will support recovering from server errors.

Comment: Hi Eyal, Thanks for the update. We will watch out for release 1.4. Let us know if you still need further detail from us. Regards Harry